# Combine merging database and network request outputs together

Tags: swift, combine

I consider how I can make stream that merges outputs from database and network request together in the following way:

1. returns current state from database
2. makes request, saved data to database, and returns them do caller via combine publisher

```
let cachePublisher = dao.read().eraseToAnyPublisher()
let networkPublisher = service.fetch()
    .flatMap { response in 
         // here i can return network fetched data back but I prefer not to do it 
         dao.update(with: response) 
         // maybe .map { _ in response } 
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
 return Publishers.MergeMany(cachePublisher, networkPublisher).eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Is there any better solution or operator in Combine that I can do side effects?
I consider `handleEvents(receiveOutput: )` but `dao.update(with: response)` returns publisher so it doesn't execute without subscriber subscribing to it in such handleEvents.

Comment: I don't quite understand. What's not good about your current solution?

Comment: Does `read()` emits every time the database updates?

Comment: No it doesn't. It is promise-like Future used inside. 
To emit updates every time I would need to use NSFetchResultContorller I think. But I doesn't need it here I think. Just cached and refreshed data suffice.
And inside update() I would perefer to return just number of updated rows/objects instead of passed response

Comment: So if you return the response (suitably mapped maybe) then that would mean the subscriber gets the cached value, then the updated value. Isn't that what you want?